# can anyone suggest me good chemistry video lectures

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

Can anyone please suggest me some websites from where i can get free chemistry video lectures?it must be relevant to iit jee syllabus.

Comment: What type of chemistry?

Comment: @A.K video lectures on organic,physical and inorganic.it must be of iit jee level,if you haven't heard about iit jee then take it to be undergrad level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This channel has a lot of great videos on physical chemistry.
https://www.youtube.com/user/TMPChem/

Answer (score 3):

I find [Free Lance Teach](https://www.youtube.com/user/freelanceteach/playlists) to be a quality in-depth source for most chemistry concepts.